# HTML table cell positioning elements so that they are stacked in a specific area of the cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

How would you position elements in an html table th cell so that one element is on the left side and is centered while another two elements are positioned to the side of the first element and are stacked on top of one another.

For example:

dog  male female

dog would be centered on the left hand side while male and female would be on top of one another and centered vertically in the th cell.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want, the example doesn't help.

Comment: how many cell are we talking about here?

Comment: male would be over female while dog would to the side of the male/female

Comment: @rockStar only one cell

Comment: @j08691 do you need more clarificiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is what you need. but I tried to do a `table within a table` thingy

```
<table border="1px solid black">
    <tr>

        <td>

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">Dog</td>
                    <td>male</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>female</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Here's a fiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Xcn5K/).

Answer (score 0):

Just a slightly different approach - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/ahu26/1/)

The "final" version would depend on how many boxes you need to fill, your own personal preferences, etc.
CSS

```
table {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
table td {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;

}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr> <td>Dog</td> <td> <div>Male <br> Female</div> </td></tr>
    <tr> <td>Cat</td> <td> <div>Male <br> Female</div> </td></tr>    
</table>
```